# Generating a network(graph) with a prescribed degree distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

My question is how can I generate a random network graph in python using numpy and networkX(other modules will work but currently I am focusing on these two) with 1000 nodes and a given degree distribution as shown in the picture where k is the number of edges and P(k) is the probability of a node will connect with a certain number of edges. Thanks a lot. [degree distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uf3J.png)

```py
p_k = [0, .1, .35, .25, .2, .1, .04, .01, .02, .02, .01]
k = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Look at the configuration model network tool in networkx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the implementation for 100 nodes. 
Please note that I modified your original probabilities to sum to 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p_k = [0, .01, .35, .25, .2, .1, .04, .01, .01, .02, .01]
k = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

expected_degree_sequence = np.random.choice(
  k, 
  100,
  p = p_k
)

G = nx.configuration_model(expected_degree_sequence)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting graph]